High Ntoskrnl CPU (and Battery) Usage Probably linked to Intel Display Driver
The bug shows on driver versions 31.xx more than on the newer ones (32.xx) , and on both versions it never shows if the Intel Graphics Command Center App is running and the screen is On (and immediatly shows back if said app is closed by quitting fron the tray icon, noting that on 32.xx driver vesions it doesnt show even if the screen is off as long as the intel app is running, contrary to version 31.xx)
I have an Acer Nitro 5 Laptop with an Intel i5-12450 and an Nvidia RTX 4060

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
